# How to do Page Not Found in JSF application?

Tags: jsf

How to do Page Not Found in JSF application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in `web.xml`:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/pageNotFound.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```